# In SignalR, is it possible to simulate a reconnect for testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I understand that SignalR continually attempts to reconnect if a connection fails for any reason. What's the best way to test my server and client's response to this?

Answer (score 7):

In order for the Client to try to reconnect, you need to configure the [HubConnectionBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnectionbuilder?view=signalr-js-latest) with the [withAutomaticReconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnectionbuilder?view=signalr-js-latest#withautomaticreconnect--) method. The JavaScript code looks something like this:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${apiUrl}/subscribe/change`)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();
```

Once that is set, the client will try to reconnect when the connection is lost.

Internally, when SignalR is disconnecting, it calls the `stopInternal` function.

If you want to do some manual testing to make sure that your handlers are being fired and they do what you expect them to do. You can save the connection in a `const` and fire the events yourself.

What I did:

1. Created the connection like in the code above,
2. Cached the connection in the `window` object.

```
    window.signalR = connection;
```

3. Opened the browser console, clicked the three dots on the left and navigated to `Network conditions`.

[image]

4. Updated `Network throttling` to offline.

[image]

5. And finally ran:

```
signalR.connection.stopInternal();
```

And my `onreconnecting` handler started firing. It runs 4 times by default. It looks like this:

```
connection.onreconnecting(error => {
  console.log('Reconnecting interval', error);
});
```

NOTE: This strategy is for development and some manual testing only. I wouldn't recommend using the `window` object for unit tests or integration tests.

A similar strategy can be achieved by caching your connection on some internal variables to be used by unit tests.

Comment: This is an excellent solution but my client is a UWP app. I wonder if i can do the same with firewall ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916046/2929675

Before the WebSocket connection gets opened, you must execute this script to monkey patch the browsers WebSocket function:

```
const sockets = [];
const nativeWebSocket = window.WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(...args){
  const socket = new nativeWebSocket(...args);
  sockets.push(socket);
  return socket;
};
```

Now you have access to all WebSocket connections via the sockets array.
And when you want to trigger a reconnect, you can call

```
sockets[0].close();
```

using the index of the connection you want to close.

When SignalR automatic reconnect is enabled, it will automatically try to open a new connection, and the `Reconnecting` and `Reconnected` events get fired.

It's a bit hacky, but it's the best solution I have found so far.

It looks like there is also some progress in the chromium issue to support this in the dev tools: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246

Answer (score 0):

To test disconnecting on the server: browse to another page.

To test disconnecting on the client: reset the server (IISreset?).

Comment: You got those wrong. To test reconnect after the server goes down use iisreset. To simulate client connection dropping (good luck) pull the network cable :)

Comment: So, you mean... You really do need BOTH ends to create a connection? Did you create SignalR or something?!? Ah, I see... YOU DID! - *Bowing my head and slowly walking away backwards* -

Comment: Pulling the network cable won't accurately simulate a client connection dropping when you're using Azure SignalR Service. Since your dev machine is connecting over the internet to ASRS, it'll behave similarly to what occurs when you run iisreset; all clients forcibly disconnected, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Updated berhir's snippet for TypeScript

```
class MockWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    static sockets: WebSocket[] = [];

    constructor(url: string | URL, protocols?: string | string[]) {
        super(url, protocols);

        MockWebSocket.sockets.push(this);
    }
}
window.WebSocket = MockWebSocket;
```

to close a socket:

```
MockWebSocket.sockets[index].close();
```