# Sentry not capture all console errors with ConsoleCapture

Tags: javascript, websocket, error-handling, next.js, sentry

I have a problem with capturing console errors with Sentry in Next.js app.

So problem is that, somewhere inside a library which we do not have access to, we have following error with WebSocket `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state`

It is clearly seemed in chrome debug panel
[image: WebSocket error]

But not sent to a sentry initialized with this code in `next.config.js`

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');
const { CaptureConsole } = require('@sentry/integrations');

const nextConfig = {
    assetPrefix: process.env.PUBLIC_URL || '',
    reactStrictMode: true,
    poweredByHeader: false,
    future: {
        webpack5: true,
    },
}

const sentryOptions = {
    silent: true,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    integrations: [
        new CaptureConsole({
            levels: ['error'],
        }),
    ],
    errorHandler: (err, _invokeErr, compilation) => {
        compilation.warnings.push('Sentry CLI Plugin: ' + err.message);
    },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [(config) => withSentryConfig(config, sentryOptions), {}]
    ],
    nextConfig,
);
```

And `sentry.client.config.js` is

```js
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import { CaptureConsole } from '@sentry/integrations';
import { Integrations } from '@sentry/tracing';

Sentry.init({
    dsn: '...',
    attachStacktrace: true,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    release: process.env.RELEASE,
    sampleRate: 1,
    tracesSampleRate: 0.2,
    integrations: [
        new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
            beforeNavigate: (context) => ({
                ...context,
                name: window.location.pathname,
            }),
        }),
        new CaptureConsole({
            levels: ['error'],
        }),
    ],
});
```

Althought another `console.error` messages successfully sends to Sentry.

Maybe that error just not printed with `console.error` and handled in some lower level?
Then how we can log it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a direction and not as a complete solve and its not straight forward , instead of relying on `CaptureConsole` - can you not listen for `socket.onclose`  and use a  `Sentry.captureException(` to send the error payload?

To capture the socket exceptions

Get all open websockets

```
const sockets = [];
const nativeWebSocket = window.WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(...args){
  const socket = new nativeWebSocket(...args);
  sockets.push(socket);
  return socket;
};
setTimeout(() => {
  // or create a button which, when clicked, does something with the sockets
  console.log(sockets);
}, 1000);
// via : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916046/13749957
```

OR use `wshook`

https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook

Once this is achieved and you have all sockets in play, tag on to the onclose and send it to sentry

```
exampleSocket.onclose = function (event) {
   Sentry.captureException(...args) 
};
```